# How to Partition Your internal harddrive in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning

I am a newbie in ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I want to partition my hard drive of 320GB so that i can divide it into 2 or more partitons. How to proceed? can anybody help?

Already installed gparted but i am not able to unmount my /dev/sda1 nor am i able to create a new partion table.

when i select unmount /dev/sda1 the message is: Most likely other partitions are also mounted on these mount points. You are advised to unmount them manually.

when i select create partion table the msg is: 2 partitions are currently active on device /dev/sda.
![This is my Hard drive properties in gpart][1]

Comment: how to use a live boot? can you also tell me that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to unmount the partition that you booted from is like trying to change a tire while you are driving the car.

To live boot you must have a Live DVD/USB. If you don't have that first download the iso image file from The [Ubuntu web page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Now you will need to different follow instructions depending on if you want to create a Live DVD or a Live USB.

For DVD [follow the instructions on the official Ubuntu page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu).

For USB [follow the instructions on the official Ubuntu page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

1. Once the DVD/USB is ready you have to boot from that. How you do it
   depends on your computer and varies from model to model.
2. Reboot your computer. When the first image shows press the
   <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to boot
   from the DVD or USB.
3. Then choose **"Try Ubuntu without installing"** and Ubuntu will boot
   from DVD/USB.
4. Then proceed with Gparted.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you i booted from a live USB. partioned my hard drive and then went to disk utility and created more partion.

Answer (score 0):

GParted is ok, but you must boot your system from a live system. You can take the usb drive/ dvd you installed Ubuntu from.

Comment: hmm...sorry can you tell me how to boot from a live system using gpart?

Comment: First boot a live system, then use gparted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the lesson [How To Partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition) and this is about partitions that are required to run Ubuntu and optional [Disk Space](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace). It's also the best to partition during clean installation.