# partitioning in ubuntu with gparted cant resize

Tags: partitioning, 14.04

I opened gparted and as i can see i have 3 partitions(or i think so) first one sda1 (236 mb) its ext2 type file and its booting point, second one is sda2(rest of the hdd 1.36 tb) extended ntfs type file and i have third one that is within the sda2 called sda5 it takes the same space as sda 2 and its file type is crypt luks, so when i try to resize the sda2 i cant resize it not for even 1 mb, i dont know if that crypt luks file is causing the problem, so i dont know what to do, by the way i can format the crypt luks(sda5) file that in inside sda 2 but i dont know if i should.Can anyone help me please? here are the pictures when i open gparted [image: http://imgur.com/b54sKGw] when i try to resize sda 2 [image: http://imgur.com/5r9Syvb] i think i did use encryption i mean while it is booting i type password and its says sda5/scrypt set up succefully or something like that and then it goes to my login screen where i type username and pass that is it

Comment: Adding a screenshot may help (you can use http://imgur.com to upload it) - did you choose a method of encryption when installing Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Partition Your internal harddrive in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/413120/how-to-partition-your-internal-harddrive-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

Comment: Also see [Rsizing boot partition with full disk encryption](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184358/resizing-boot-partition-with-full-disk-encryption). Basically it can't be done without erasing everything.

Comment: You don't have an NTFS partition. You have an [extended partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition), with only one logical paritition in it, the LUKS volume.